# Uninitialized Tag constant in Rails 3 with Acts_As_Taggable_On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, constants, acts-as-taggable-on

This controller action worked perfectly in Rails 2.3.x:

```
def show
  @title = Tag.find(params[:id]).name
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @messages = Post.paginate(Post.find_tagged_with(@tag), 
              :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => "updated_at DESC")
  @related_tags = @related_entries.collect{|x|x.tags}.flatten.uniq
  @related_tags.delete(@tag)
end
```

But while migrating my application to Rails 3 I run into this error in Tags#show:

```
uninitialized constant TagsController::Tag
```

It's not liking the `Tag` constant. Has anyone else had this issue?

I'm using Rails 3.0.0RC and Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try including the complete namespace e.g.

```
@title = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id]).name
```

Comment: Very helpful!  but its obviously a lot to type.  is there an easy way to configure it so you can just refer to "Tag"?

Answer (score 10):

You can also define the model in your app:

```
# app/models/tag.rb
class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
end

# app/models/tagging.rb
class Tagging < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging
end
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Every app should do this. (This just saved us from a Ruby 1.9.3 issue)